# How to get started with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, angular, npm, html2canvas

Okay, so this might seem like a simple question...
But I'm new to part of stuff. On http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started it shows a very small tutorial...
When I run `npm install -g html2canvas`, it works great.
Now comes the part where I'm actually lost. Where do I put the code `import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';`?
Do I just put this at the top of the javascript file?

Comment: Why don't you try and see? ;)

Comment: The thing is, I'm using angular. And is this "import"-part of it needed on all pages or can I load it once in the code and that's it? And the " from 'html2canvas' " part, do I need to add a searchpath to it to make it found or whatever.

Comment: If you're using angular, then you'll need to add the tag to your question, because it's now a completely different question. Yes, you'll need to add it to every file that uses it. This won't affect performance, because your typescript loader sees that you imported the library and when transpiled will only be added once and not for every single time you imported it somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, alright. I understand so far. When adding the import, where do I import from? Searchpath I mean. What exactly am I importing? The node modules?

Answer (score 0):

`import` statement is an [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) feature, they are intended to be used at the very top of any Javascript file.

[MDN Definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

> The import statement is used to import bindings which are exported by
>   another module. Imported modules are in strict mode whether you
>   declare them as such or not. The import statement cannot be used in
>   embedded scripts.

so, in your case simply use `import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';` at the top of your file.

However, if you're not using [[image]google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) or some kind of transpiler ([babel](/questions/tagged/babel) for example), [then it won't work](https://caniuse.com/#search=import), because it's currently not supported in every navigator.

If you're not using a transpiler or google-chrome, think about using [requirejs](/questions/tagged/requirejs)